# Redux Form Validation firing on load (UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS)

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

All required fields have their validation triggered by `UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS` on load of the form component. I don't think this is a bug I believe it to be a code issue (as it used to work - although I have recently updated)

So my question is - What could cause `UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS` to fire at this stage? The field also has no value (`undefined`) yet passes through my function and fires an error as 'Required' like when a field has been touched.

`export const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required';`

I can put an extra check in eg: `value && value !== undefined ? undefined : 'Required';` but then I don't get the error when the textField has been touched.

Any ideas how to debug without totally stripping back? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In the last day I ran into this problem, too, and struggled to find any suitable solution, but through an amalgamation of lots of different issues on redux-form repo and lots of re-reading the docs and peeking at the source I've got something that should address your question. Granted, almost a year later, but hopefully it helps someone.

**Note:** The "magic" as it were is denoted by a comment so if your config object for reduxForm looks different I wouldn't pay much mind.

```js
import { reduxForm, getFormValues, isDirty } from 'redux-form';

const formName = 'brilliantForm';

let MyForm = reduxForm({
    form: formName,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    asyncValidate,
    asyncBlurFields: [],
})(ComponentToWrap);

MyForm = connect(
    state => ({
        formValues: getFormValues(formName)(state),
        initialValues: {
            fieldOne: '',
            fieldTwo: '',
        },
        shouldValidate: () => isDirty(formName)(state), // This is the magic
    })
)(MyForm);

export default MyForm;
```

The gist here is that if there are initial values for your form redux-form is going to validate them by default unless you tell it not to via [shouldValidate()](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-shouldvalidate-params-boolean-code-optional-). The [isDirty selector](https://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/selectors.md/) makes quick work of limiting validation to *after* the form has been touched/interacted with.

**NOTE:** As of [7.1](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v7.1.0) `shouldValidate()` has been split up and deprecated in favor of [shouldError()](https://redux-form.com/7.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-shoulderror-params-boolean-code-optional-) and [shouldWarn()](https://redux-form.com/7.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-shouldwarn-params-boolean-code-optional-).

Comment: You can also do the shouldValidate() bits in the object passed to reduxForm() as well. It would be something like shouldValidate: params => params.props.dirty

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the solution above does not work for me :( Maybe if you could take a look at my question, I'd appreciate! https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/96037385