# Redux Form + React Native Elements firing validation too soon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form in React Native, along with React Native Elements to create forms.
The problem is, after the screen is rendered, the validations are getting called before the user has even had a chance to touch the input fields, showing input validations error too early.

My code:

FormInput:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Input } from "react-native-elements";

export default FormInput = (props) => {
    const { input, meta: { error }, ...inputProps } = props

    return <Input {...inputProps}
        onChangeText={input.onChange}
        onBlur={input.onBlur}
        onFocues={input.onFocus}
        value={input.value}
        errorMessage={error}
        />
}
```

LoginForm:

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field, isDirty } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { required, email } from 'redux-form-validators'

import FormInput from "./FormInput";

import styles from "./Styles/LoginFormStyles";
import Colors from '../Themes/Colors'

const bla = (value) =>  {
    console.tron.log('value = ' + value)
    return value !== undefined ? undefined : 'is required'
}

const LoginForm = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit, submitting } = props

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={require('../Images/logo.png')} style={styles.logoContainer} resizeMode='center' />
            <View style={styles.buttonHolderContainer}>
                <Field name="email" validate={bla} textContentType="emailAddress" keyboardType="email-address" autoCapitalize = 'none' component={FormInput} placeholder="Email" containerStyle={styles.inputContainerHolder} />
                <Field name="password" validate={[required()]} secureTextEntry component={FormInput} placeholder="Senha" containerStyle={styles.inputContainerHolder} />
                <Button title="Entrar" style={{ marginTop: 10 }} buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: Colors.appColor }} titleStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
                    onPress={handleSubmit} loading={submitting} disabled={submitting}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default reduxForm({ form: 'LoginForm'})(LoginForm)
```

Versions:

- "react-native": "0.57.7",
- "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
- "react-navigation": "3.1.3",
- "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
- "redux": "^4.0.0",
- "redux-form": "^8.1.0"

The Redux call chain:
[image]
As you can see, the UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS event is getting dispatched before any user interactions to the input.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe deferred creation will do the trick? Search for the `lazy` option: https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/formReducer.html

Comment: @Ahmad I'm using ReduxForm, not React Redux Form :)

Comment: oh whups, sorry! so many libraries out there :s

Comment: No worries man, thanks for looking at it

Comment: I ended up changing from react-redux to Formik. I know this does not answer my own question, but I found much easier to use Formik over React-Redux. Anyway, thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at using the helper function [shouldError()](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/docs/api/ReduxForm.md#shoulderrorparams--boolean-optional) so you can control when `redux-form` chooses to perform its validation.

Although the code example is out-of-date because it uses the deprecated `shouldValidate()` you can still get an idea of how to use `shouldError()` by taking a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50143391/250496).

Answer (score 0):

Inside of meta you have properties like touched, visited etc. You can use those property to show error based on condition:

> **meta.touched:** true if the field has been touched. By default this will be set when the field is blurred.

> **meta.visited:** true if this field has ever had focus. It will only work if you are passing onFocus to your input element.

So the errorField can be:

```
 errorMessage={meta.touched && error}
```